# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value and Invalid write of size

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I have some strange problems connected with memory. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Pair{
char *key;
unsigned long long int value;
};


int main()
{
    Pair p;
    char string[256];
    char path[100];
    int i;
    int l;
    std::cout<<"ENTER THE DIRECTORY"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>path;
    FILE *f = fopen(path,"wb");
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        std::cin>>string;
        p.key = new char[strlen(string)];
        l = strlen(p.key);
        std::cin>>p.value;
        strcpy(p.key,string);
        if (!fwrite(&l,sizeof(int),1,f))
            perror("ERROR: ");
        if (!fwrite(p.key, sizeof(char),l,f))
             perror("ERROR: ");
        if (!fwrite(&p.value, sizeof(unsigned long long int),1,f))
             perror("ERROR: ");
        std::cout<<p.key<<" "<<p.value<<std::endl;
        delete [] p.key;
    }
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen(path,"rb");
        for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        if (!fread(&l,sizeof(int),1,f))
            perror("ERROR: ");
        p.key = new char[l];
        if (!fread(p.key,sizeof(char),l,f))
            perror("ERROR: ");
        if (!fread(&p.value, sizeof(unsigned long long int),1,f))
            perror("ERROR: ");
        std::cout<<p.key<<" "<<p.value<<std::endl;
        delete [] p.key;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

But valgrind says, that conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value in l = strlen(p.key); What is more, without valgrind after reading from file it doesn't show key, only value.

```
==10157== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10157==    at 0x402D3EB: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10157==    by 0x8048A84: main (main.cpp:25)
==10157== 
==10157== Invalid write of size 1
==10157==    at 0x402D506: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10157==    by 0x8048AB6: main (main.cpp:27)
==10157==  Address 0x434c1bc is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==10157==    at 0x402ADFC: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10157==    by 0x8048A74: main (main.cpp:24)
```

If I change l = strlen(p.key) to l = strlen(string) valgrind says

```
==10030== Invalid write of size 1
==10030==    at 0x402D506: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10030==    by 0x8048AB9: main (main.cpp:27)
==10030==  Address 0x434c1bb is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==10030==    at 0x402ADFC: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10030==    by 0x8048A74: main (main.cpp:24)
==10030== 
==10030== Invalid read of size 1
==10030==    at 0x402D3F3: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10030==    by 0x40D33E4: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==10030==    by 0x8048B85: main (main.cpp:34)
==10030==  Address 0x434c1bb is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==10030==    at 0x402ADFC: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10030==    by 0x8048A74: main (main.cpp:24)
```

The same thing is for strcpy function.
I also tried initalize p.key with '\0' by memset, but valgrind writes

```
==10562== Invalid write of size 4
==10562==    at 0x403087D: memset (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
...
valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:277 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
 end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
 invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
 probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.
```

So, why I have these problems in this simple code and what are possible ways for their decision, please help me.

Comment: p.key is a char * which needs to be allocated to and written to ( in that order ) before reading from. you arent writing to it before attempting to get its strlen ( reading )

Comment: If you use `std::string` you'd be surprised how many errors just disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
p.key = new char[strlen(string)];
l = strlen(p.key);
```

You are using uninitialized `p.key`. Since `strlen` depends on a null terminated character array, the call `strlen(p.key)` leads to undefined behavior.

**Problem 2**

```
strcpy(p.key,string);
```

is also a problem. You did not allocate enough memory to be able to hold the terminating null character in `p.key`. You need to use:

```
p.key = new char[strlen(string)+1];
                            // ^^ Need the additional character
```

**Problem 3**

The lines below are good for restoring the contents of the file. However, the string is not null terminated.

```
p.key = new char[l];
if (!fread(p.key,sizeof(char),l,f))
```

You need to use:

```
p.key = new char[l+1];
               // ^^ Need the additional character
if (!fread(p.key,sizeof(char),l,f))
p.key[l] = '\0`;
```